# Affine scheme, quasi-coherence and open cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question regarding quasi-coherent schemes which are affine (and which are also assumed to be Noetherian). Let this affine scheme be defined as $X=\text{Spec}(A)$, where $A$ is a (noetherian) ring. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. By the definition of quasi-coherence, there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i}$ and a set of $A_i$-modules $M_i$ with $\mathscr{F}|_{U_i}\cong\tilde{M_i}$, where $A_i$ is a ring and $U_i=\text{Spec}(A_i)$.

Reminding that we assume affineness, and given the knowledge about $A_i$ and if we assume that the open cover  $\{U_i\}_{i}$ is non-trivial, can we say that there exists an $A$-module $M$ such that $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})=M$ and also $\mathscr{F}\cong\tilde{M}$ which can be constructed from the set $\{(U_i,M_i)\}_{i}$?

In the following I am trying to approach the problem from different angles. I also note that $A_i$ is of the form of a localization  $A_{\mathfrak{p_1}...\mathfrak{p}_n}$, for appropriately chosen $\mathfrak{p}_{1,...,n}\in\text{Spec}(A),n<\infty$ and the given definition of $M_i$. In some way, after while writing this question and some rethinking, I am not sure whether such an $A$-module $M$ in every case of quasi-coherence necessarily exists. Also, $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf, so for an open cover (also assuming a Zariski topology), $\mathscr{F}|_{U_i\cap U_j}\cong \tilde{M_i}|_{U_i\cap U_j}\cong \tilde{M_j}|_{U_i\cap U_j}$. I was thinking about constructing $\tilde{M}$ as a direct sum $\bigoplus_i \tilde{M}_i$. The global section of this direct sum could be $(M_1,...,M_n)$ and other localisations $\bigoplus_i \tilde{M}_i(U_i\cap U)$ at $U$ open in $X$. It seems like $\bigoplus_i \Gamma(U_i,\tilde{M}_i)$ might in fact be seen as an $A$-module, each $M_i$ being an $A_i$-module and as indicated above and $A\subset A_i$, being a localization. A similar technique should also work for the sections at $U=\text{Spec}(A')$ with $A'$ a localization of the ring $A$. But after all, it remains unclear to me whether my reasoning is a valid approach.

Comment: Yes, this is true. See [Leamma 26.7.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IB) in the stacks project, for example.

Comment: @Daniel  So you agree that the above construction using this direct sum is correct?

Comment: Your construction is **very** wrong. Try seeing what it spits out when you consider $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$, the open cover $\{D(x),D(x-1)\}$, and the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. (There's a lot wrong in your final paragraph, it would be somewhat exhausting to point all the errors out, please go read a text that does this in detail.)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for telling me. It seems a bit weird to say this in mathematics ... sometimes if something feels wrong when writing it, it will rather likely turn out to be wrong indeed (at least in this case). Putting this aside, if such a construction existed, would you give me a hint how to formulate such an $A$-module? Or is there no such $A$-module necessarily, in general, after all?

Comment: $\mathscr{F}$, being a quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme $X\cong\operatorname{Spec} A$, is isomorphic to the sheaf associated to the $A$-module $\Gamma(\mathscr{F},X)$. So if you can calculate the global sections via the sheaf condition on your open cover (this requires some knowledge of the overlaps), there you go.